# push notifications: sounds and badges

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working with push notifications and i have a doubt: if in my script (server-side) there are badge and sound, but the user set sounds and badges off... what happens?

I mean: i need to register in my database every setting for every token, or i send the notification and the iPhone does all the work? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the user settings. The user will receive the alerts he allowed. So if he doesn't want to have the sound and he switch it off. You can still send it and he just receive the alert and or badge...

Comment: Your answer in incorrect! I have posted the right answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If the user switches off a particular notification type in user settings, such notifications are not received by the application. For example:- lets say I registered for sound and badge notifications but I disabled the badge notifications in user settings, the application will only receive the sound notifications from now until I enable the badge notifications in user settings or register again for alter notifications too. Re-registering for badge notifications wont enable the badge notifications since they are disbled in user settings.